# powershell endpoint GPO update

Tags: powershell, module, refresh, endpoint, gpo

In my environment we have roughly 20k endpoints. GPOs get pushed but not "managed" at least not audited well. The end goal is to have the ability to query a single endpoint and determine the last GPO update that it received and 'enabled'. Ultimately a timestamp-ish type attribute would be optimal because we are trying to look into endpoints that are outliers and have not responding to long time GPOs. Im trying to get this functionality in Powershell becasue we already have a multithreaded script for our domain attribute collections- i just want to bake this in as well. I have already looked over the GroupPolicy Module commands and am not really seeing a way to get specific instances for specific endpoints. I did read about a possibility of GPO updates being stored in the registry? Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say look at event log of the systems as that will get you a time stamp.  You are right, you can find it in the [registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201453).  However, I was not able to see any kind of time stamp when these GPOs were applied.

It might take a little bit to develop the code as event logs are a bit of a headache to work with in POSH, BUT it will be worth it in the end.  The path for the event logs on a system is this "Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Group Policy".  The event code by looking at my system is 5117 for the operational event log.  This should be a good starting place for you.

Comment: I'm already pulling Ina number of event logs and have built a conditional parsing script in powershell- this is certainly a great path to travel down- I do have a follow up question for you- since GPs can be "pushed" but not "enabled" is 5117 the eID for the GPO refresh or logging that the GP has been instated? Thanks for this- I will weave this into dev testing first thing Friday!

Comment: If it is in the registry, couldn't I get-child property last modified time and recurse through that dir? Or is that too 'hacky':/

Comment: Depends and what your end goal is.  If you are on a time crunch and only need to do that, then looking at the registry might be a great option (since it is faster to do a reg query than event log parse).  However, you would need to test when those keys are updated.  Are they update every time the client side extensions are refreshed or are they update only when there is a delta with the GPO version numbers?  I would say you would have to definitely further test that.

Comment: agreed. Event parsing is so cumbersome- powerful data- impossibly slow. These two avenues may be one in the same data wise- thinking about this more the reg mod would trip a client event. Your comments have helped! I appreciate your take on this and this has given me some direction. I'll post back here after I test in my environment. Thanks again

Comment: However, if you have extra time in the world for dev'ing and making something cool, I would say go down the event log route.  Not because it may be easier to pull information but it will allow you to have options open in case you need to perform a similar action like parsing the security logs or what not.  I personally like the idea for expandability.  But, it boils down to time/priorities of the boss.

Comment: As far as the question about the 5117, just states that group policy session has ended.  You can look up the meaning [here](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/Default.aspx).

Comment: One thing you can do is have the end clients run a scheduled task X times a day and then just have your script go and collect an results file...

Only problem with that is sometimes GPP don't always clean up well and you have deploy another GPP to delete the schedule task that you create.  Let me know how things go for you.

Comment: True. I do this for security and app logs as well- just for other IOCs. The main hindrance that I have in my environment is old old T1 lines to remote facilities- if you start doing to much client side you can saturate the connection with that controller- and POOF- unintentional DOS attack. :( thanks for your response! ^^^